# Where do I place cpp file when header is in /usr/local/include?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I wrote a c++ class(files `class.h` and `class.cpp`) that I want to use in a c++ application `app.cpp` from multiple directories on my linux system. Therefore, I moved the `class.h` and `class.cpp` files to `/usr/local/include/`. I tried to compile `app.cpp` using `g++ -o app app.cpp` which results in an `undefined reference` error(probably since g++ does not find the `class.cpp` file).

I figured out that I can fix this error by either writing the content of `class.cpp` directly into `class.h` or by explicitly specifying the location of `class.cpp` with the extended command `g++ -o app app.cpp /usr/local/include/class.cpp`. Obviously, both solutions are not satisfactory.

Presumably, someone who does this stuff more regularly(I'm not an computer science student) can give me a quick solution to my problem. Therefore, I ask now instead of investing more hours into searching the web.

Comment: In a compiled library (shared or static archive) hosted in /usr/local/lib. Solve the problem of building the library first (obviously), which is prime google-fu material.

Comment: I'd put my the files in `jonas/jonas/class.h` and `jonas/jonas/src/class.cpp` and then the consumer may specify the `-I/users/eljay/project/jonas` on command line for the compiler, and refer to the header by `#include "jonas/class.h"` from my own code.  That allows me to decide where I want the **jonas** dependent project to reside.

Comment: `undefined reference` errors have nothing to do with the header file.  The header file contains declarations of the function, and matter only to the compiler.  The definitions of the functions belong in a library and matter to the linker.  `undefined reference` is a linker error, not a compiler error.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for the hint. I now have a `class.a` file located in `/usr/local/lib` but unfortunately, `g++ -o app app.cpp` gives the same error. Is there a way that g++ automatically finds the class.cpp, class.o or class.a file? Or do I have to explicitly specify it, as proposed by @Eljay

Comment: You would normally name the file `libclass.a` and add `-lclass` to the linker flags.

Comment: The library should be called `libclass.a`, and the compile command line to use it should be something like `g++ -o app -lclass app.cpp`. The `-lclass` will tell the linker to search the default library search path (which `/usr/local/lib` is *probably* in; if not it can be added with `-L /usr/local/lib`_ for a file called `libclass.a` or `libclass.so`.

Comment: Yay it works. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a static compiled library using `g++ -c class.cpp` and `ar rvs libclass.a class.o`(can also create a shared library here)
2. Compile using `g++ -o app app.cpp -lclass`